# How to setup an angular project in MacOS in vs code

Tags: angular, macos, setup-project

I am installed angular on my m1 Mac and while setting up the project using the command : "ng new" and after that it is showing ✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
[Not able to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxQQW.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to delete the package-lock.json and delete the node_modules first then ng new command again. Make sure to install the latest ng cli in global using `npm i -g @angular/cli`